How to group 3d points closer than a distance threshold in python?
I have a set of 3d points and I want find any groups of them that are "close together" based on some threshold distance and make a group (removing them from my set). So I end up with a set of groups of points and the remainder.
The definition of "close together" would be that they fit in a sphere of less than the threshold distance, so I don't get a line of points in one group.
I need to do this in python, which I'm not very familiar with (cpp coder). Its a precompiled so it doesn't have to be that fast and there's not likely to be more than a few thousand points.
Ideally I want it to be fairly simple to implement coz it uses a library or is simple.
Any pointers to algorith or sample code would be appreciated.

Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please edit your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the full text of any errors or tracebacks, all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a minimal reproducible example.

IIUC, you can build a DistanceBand with your threshold, then remove the connected_components :
import networkx as nx
from libpysal import weights

# an example of a Set of points / a list of (x,y,z)
SP = list(nx.spectral_layout(nx.dodecahedral_graph(), dim=3).values())

G = weights.DistanceBand.from_array(SP, threshold=0.7).to_networkx()

to_keep, to_remove = [], []

for cc in nx.connected_components(G):
    if len(cc) > 1:
        to_remove.extend(cc)
    else:
        to_keep.extend(cc)

Output :
(
    # to_keep
    [6, 7, 11, 18],
    # to_remove
    [0, 1, 8, 9, 10, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16, 17, 12, 13, 14]
)

Or, if you want to replace them with their centroid, you can compute the mean :
import numpy as np

new_sp = []
for cc in nx.connected_components(G):
    if len(cc) > 1:
        centroid = np.r_[SP][list(cc)].mean(axis=0)
        new_sp.append(centroid)
    else:
        new_sp.append(SP[cc.pop()])


Edges (with a distance < 0.7) :
[
    {"path": "P00 to P01", "distance": 0.4468164592001661},
    {"path": "P15 to P16", "distance": 0.4468164592001661},
    {"path": "P09 to P10", "distance": 0.5088742649122014},
    {"path": "P04 to P05", "distance": 0.5088742649122014},
    {"path": "P02 to P03", "distance": 0.5758406756748694},
    {"path": "P12 to P13", "distance": 0.5758406756748694},
    {"path": "P03 to P19", "distance": 0.6055080439746322},
    {"path": "P13 to P14", "distance": 0.6055080439746322},
    {"path": "P08 to P09", "distance": 0.6214374803748165},
    {"path": "P04 to P17", "distance": 0.6214374803748165},
    {"path": "P01 to P08", "distance": 0.6943680760117862},
    {"path": "P16 to P17", "distance": 0.6943680760117862},
    # ...
]


That's amazing, thank-you. How would I walk the sets of points that have been clustered and access the cluster center? I actually want to replace each cluster with a new point to represent the collection. Probably based on either the center of the cluster or the point closest to the center.

You're welcome ;) I added an option to replace the clusters with a single point, see update.

I've just got my coding using this example working, thank-you again, it made a task I thought was going to be somewhat challenging very straight forward.

I'm not sure if I understoo correctly but I believe the problem you are describing can be summarized into: create the minimum amount of spheres of a given diameter that cover a set of points belonging to a 3D space.
There is a post on the CS stack exchange describing this exact problem together with a description of an algorithm that could solve it: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48412/cover-points-with-minimal-number-of-spheres-of-fixed-radius
It seems that the solution lies in solving an NP-hard problem, so depending on the size of your input, it might not be feasible. There is this repository that seems to contain an implementation for the algorithm suggested in the CS stack exchange post: https://github.com/farjasju/CliqueCover. It also contains a heuristic implementation which will probably not lead to an optimal solution but it might be a good enough one to fit your use case.
The post also suggests taking a look into clustering, which I think might not suit your needs but could be a direction to explore if you find out the above approach doesn't work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
